# R Keras - super simple LSTM example with fit error

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm trying to build a toy model to demonstrate how LSTMs can predict the next few iteration of a sequence. My code runs without any errors until the last line.

```
# Simulating dummy data
seq <- data.frame(x_train = (seq(0,8, 1)/10), y_train = (seq(0,8, 1)/10))
seq$x_train <- seq$x_train + 0.1

# Reshaping
x_train <- array_reshape(seq$x_train, dim = c(9,1,1))
y_train <- array_reshape(seq$y_train, dim = c(9,1))

# Checking dimensions
dim(x_train); dim(y_train)

# Building the model
m <- keras_model_sequential()
m %>% 
  layer_lstm(units = 10, input_shape =c(9,1), batch_size = 9, return_sequences = T, stateful = T) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)

summary(m)

# Compiling
m %>% compile(loss = "mse", optimizer = "adam")
```

This is where the issue arises -

```
for (i in 1:9) {
  m %>% fit(object = x_train, y_train, batch_size = 1, shuffle = FALSE)
  m %>% reset_states()
}
```

I get the following error, and I'm not sure why:

`Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It still doesn't work but, shouldn't it be `x = x_train` instead of `object = x_train` where you call `fit`?

Comment: And this will give you a problem with the input dimension.